# How to use Checkbox Item in Ionic framework?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, ionic-framework

I'm developing the  mobile app with Ionic framework.  I don't know how to make a list which checked items? I tried lots of ways to do it

Could anyone help me about it ?

For example My Checkbox section code:

```
>    <ul class="list" ng-repeat="item in TreatmentsSpa">
>       <li class="item item-checkbox">
>         <label class="checkbox">
>           <input type="checkbox">
>         </label>
>       {{item.Name}}
>       </li>
```

TreatmentSpa is a JSON from Webapi

I want to make a list which include checked Item's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be this could be helpful for you.. Here i have set ng-model (treatment.selected) at run time.

```
<ion-view view-title="films" ng-controller="TreatmentSpaController">     <ion-content class="padding">
 <div class="item-accordion"
      ng-repeat="treatment in TreatmentSpa track by $index">
   <ion-item class="item item-checkbox">
     <label class="checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="treatment.selected" ng-change="updateTreatmentSpa(treatment)">
     </label>
     {{treatment.name}}
   </ion-item>
 </div>   </ion-content>
```

controller:

```
.controller('TreatmentSpaController', function($scope,$http ) {
$scope.treatmentSpaCheckedItems = [];
$scope.TreatmentSpa = [
  {name:'One'},
  {name:'Two'},
  {name:'Three'},
  {name:'Four'},
  {name:'Five'}
];

$scope.updateTreatmentSpa = function(treatment){
  console.log(' new name  :'+treatment.name);
  if(treatment.selected){
    $scope.treatmentSpaCheckedItems.push(treatment.name);
  }else{
 $scope.treatmentSpaCheckedItems.splice($scope.treatmentSpaCheckedItems.indexOf(treatment.name), 1);
  }
   console.log('checked TreatmentSpa:'+$scope.treatmentSpaCheckedItems);
};});
```